# How to publish on Azure AD my MDM App in the MDM and MAM gallery?

Tags: azure-active-directory, saas, mdm

We have a MDM solution where clients that utilize Azure AD can join and enroll (to our MDM) Windows 10 devices. The clients configure in their Tenants an **On-Premise MDM app** (that is selected from the Mobility MDM and MAM app gallery) in order to set and use our MDM.

We would like to have our MDM App showed in that gallery such as the image below. Does anyone can help me and show me some hints to make our MDM to appear in that Gallery?

I know that one step is that our MDM has to have its own Tenant in Azure AD and there create an App (my organization is developing) and set it as Multi-Tenant. But after that I am lost, I don't know what are the next steps.

Thanks in advance.

[image: with my MDM as App (green triangle) ready to be picked]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/azure-active-directory-integration-with-mdm#publish-your-mdm-app-to-azure-ad-app-gallery

to publish a on-prem based mdm, is no different than adding a normal app to the app gallery, in which case, in which case follow this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/howto-app-gallery-listing

they mention a portal that you can use and request access to submit request.

Comment: That is the way. Microsoft took some months to approve the request, though.